# How to call request using google timezone api for multiple locations in single request

Tags: google-maps

How to we search using google timezone api for multiple locations(latitude and longitude pair) in single request.

Request Ex. :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/xml?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false
```

How to pass multiple location as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> How to we search using google timezone api for multiple locations(latitude and longitude pair) in single request

Looking at the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/) there is no example, so multiple location request is most likely not supported.